# Slicing multiple dimensions in a ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

How to slice `ndarray` by multiple dimensions in one line? Check the last line in the following snippet. This seems so basic yet it gives a surprise... but why?

```
import numpy as np

# create 4 x 3 array
x = np.random.rand(4, 3)

# create row and column filters
rows = np.array([True, False, True, False])
cols = np.array([True, False, True])

print(x[rows, :].shape == (2, 3))  # True ... OK
print(x[:, cols].shape == (4, 2))  # True ... OK
print(x[rows][:, cols].shape == (2, 2))  # True ... OK
print(x[rows, cols].shape == (2, 2))  # False ... WHY???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `rows` and `cols` are boolean arrays, when you do:

```
x[rows, cols]
```

it is like:

```
x[np.where(rows)[0], np.where(cols)[0]]
```

which is:

```
x[[0, 2], [0, 2]]
```

taking the values at positions `(0, 0)` and `(2, 2)`. On the other hand, doing:

```
x[rows][:, cols]
```

works like:

```
x[[0, 2]][:, [0, 2]]
```

returning a shape `(2, 2)` in this example.

Comment: For more information take a look here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays